# Does specifying a directive create an exception after disallowing all bots at the beginning in robots.txt?

Tags: search, seo, frontend, backend, search-engine

The case is like below:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /test
```

In this case, is the Googlebot able to do its job?

I guess maybe since the file only specifies disallowing /test for the Googlebot, so there is a change that the Googlebot can do their jobs on other directories except for the /test?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?  From what I gather, all bots will be blocked from all urls, and `Googlebot` will be doubly blocked from the `/test` URL.

Comment: I am not sure. I guess maybe since the file only specifies disallowing /test for Googlebot, so there is a change that Googlebot can do its jobs on other directories except for the /test?

Comment: Googlebot specifically supports an `Allow` directive, that may do what you need it to

Answer (score 0):

question : In this case, is the Googlebot able to do its job?

answer : not this case

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

question : I guess maybe since the file only specifies disallowing /test for the Googlebot, so there is a change that the Googlebot can do their jobs on other directories except for the /test?

answer : yes exactly